# Joint distribution with undefined conditional

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have two RVs $X$ and $Y$ defined on a common probability space.

$f_y(y) = e^{-y}$ if $y\geq0$ and 0 otherwise.

Also, it is given that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ is Poisson with parameter $y$.

Poisson distribution only defined for $\lambda > 0$, so $X|Y$ is defined only for $y>0$.
So that I have a question:

> what about a joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ of $X$ and $Y$?

It is known as $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X|Y}(x,y)*f_y$. However, conditional distibution $f_{X|Y}(x,y)$ is not defined for $y<0$. What to do?

Comment: It is because the support of $Y$ is the positive real, so people usually does not care about that. Both $X$ and $Y$ are almost surely non-negative, for any point outside of the joint support $\mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{R}^+$, you can just define the conditional pmf to be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the conditional distribution $(X\mid Y=y)$ is defined "almost surely" since $P(Y>0)=1$.

This is enough to find the distribution of $(X,Y)$.

However, there is no PDF since $X$ is discrete.

Also there is no PMF since $Y$ is continuous.

You can do it by working out:$$\mathsf P(X=k\wedge Y\leq y)=\int_0^y\mathsf P(X=k\mid Y=u)f_Y(u)du$$
That expression determines the joint probability.